# Passing arguments to Compose'd functions?

Tags: r, functional-programming

I have a situation in which I'd like to pass arguments to functions linked via `Compose`.  I realize I could Curry in the arguments, but I'd like the resulting function to be more flexible than that.  Here's a simple test case to show the problem:

```
> library(functional)
> f <- function(x, scale) x^2*scale
> g <- function(y, shift) sqrt(y)+shift
> h <- Compose(f,g)
> h(1)
Error in x^2 * scale : 'scale' is missing
> h(1, scale=1, shift=0)
Error in Reduce(function(x, f) f(x), fs, ...) : 
  unused argument(s) (scale = 1, shift = 0)
```

Is there any way to use `Compose` such that it allows the resultant function to still allow arguments when being called?  `?Compose` is less than helpful, except perhaps as an elegy to a lovely keyboard.

Comment: Which package are you getting Compose from?

Comment: Andrie - Harsh!  @Dason It's (now, thanks to Josh's edit) the first line in my code :-).  Sorry, forgot to copy/paste that line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [function composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_%28computer_science%29) is formulated in computer science, all the functions have only a single argument. The `Composition` function assumes this as well. `Curry`ing is the typical way around this. One additional complication is that any additional named arguments must be passed to the correct function in the composition process.

Here are a couple of approaches:

```
h1 <- function(scale, shift)
  Compose(Curry(f,scale), Curry(g,shift))
```

`h1` takes the named parameters and creates the composed function with those curried in correctly. The return is a 1 parameter function:

```
> h1(scale=1, shift=0)(1)
[1] 1
```

Another approach is to delay the currying (and thus the composition) until the actual function evaluation. In this case, the original "Compose" function just sets everything up, but does not actually compose, returning a function which curries, composes, and evaluates.

```
ComposeDelayedCurry <- function(...) {
  fs <- list(...)
  all.formals <- lapply(fs, formals)
  function(...) {
    local.args <- list(...)
    pos.args <- lapply(all.formals, function(f) {
      local.args[names(f)[[-1]]]
    })
    curried <- lapply(seq_along(fs), function(i) {
      do.call(Curry, c(fs[[i]], pos.args[[i]]))
    })
    do.call(Compose, curried)(..1)
  }
}

h2 <- ComposeDelayedCurry(f,g)
```

Now calling `h2` will do all the work at evaluation time. This makes several assumptions. One is that the first argument to each function (and the function call) is the one that is being composed over. The second is that all other arguments are named arguments. Nothing can be passed into a function via `...`. That is because the formals to each function have to be examined to know where each argument "goes". I think this would handle not specifying arguments with default values, but I'm not completely sure.

```
> h2(1, scale=1, shift=0)
[1] 1
> h2(3, scale=5, shift=2)
[1] 8.708204
> sqrt(5*(3^2))+2
[1] 8.708204
```